# Pythonic way to handle/spread alerts class in multiple modules

Tags: python, python-3.x, design-patterns, singleton, python-module

I have a class to handle alerts that, at the end of the process, will be sent in an email. This alerts are list that are updated during the process execution.

The point is that the process uses different modules in different files so...

My question is: what is the pythonic way of handling this alerts class?

- Declare it at the beginnig of the process and pass it as argument to
  the different modules handlers?
- Maybe create it as `Singleton`?
- Any other idea is obviously welcome!

Thank you in advance!

Answer (score 0):

Well, I think this python pattern could help me...

https://github.com/faif/python-patterns/blob/master/patterns/creational/borg.py

Code Example:

```
class Borg:
    __shared_state = {}

    def __init__(self):
        self.__dict__ = self.__shared_state
        self.state = 'Init'

    def __str__(self):
        return self.state


class MyBorg(Borg):

    def __init__(self):
        Borg.__init__(self)
        self.alert_one = []
        self.alert_two = []
        ...
```

Just one thing... lists initialization should be in `MyBorg` or better in `Borg`?

Thank you!

Comment: Well, this didn'r work but Singleton did. The point is that I don't know if using Singleton in this kind of situation is good idea or not...